# Basic Question: Differentiating Related Functions (Calculus)In

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

In case anyone else is searching for an answer in the future:

### The question contained an assumption. There is no rule dictating different processing of the 2 variables based on the variable whose derivative you're seeking (x and y vis a vis ***dx***/dt and ***dy***/dt), although lord knows one might be excused for thinking there could be an extra rule that the calculus student is expected to intuit without need for explicit instruction. The fact that most problems encountered in my textbook did almost always pair x with dx/dt is a coincidence. For xy=4 you start your calculations using the product rule because--well -- xy is a product.  For 12x² = y³ - 24  you start with the power rule with 12x². The downstream consequence of applying the derivative rules to the different equations is that you use x • dy/dt in one problem and x • dx/dt in the other. But nothing was done with the intention of getting that result. By analogy to algebra, for 2x=4  you'd start using division x=4/2 on the right side of the equation but for 2³-24=-16 you'd start by evaluating the exponent 2³=8 on the left side. But there's certainly no rule that you always start processing the right side of an equation before the left. In practice, most of the problems students see have all the heavy work on the left side of the equation, but all other order-of-operations rules have precedence over the left-to-right rule.

As you can see below, one related functions solution begins with x • ***dy***/dt and another begins with x • ***dx***/dt.

***Why?***

dy/dt = dy/dx • dx/dt

y'(t)= y'(x) • x'(t)

***What part of the calculations is functioning as dy/dx?***

EXAMPLE 1
Find dx/dt:

xy = 4

To solve, you start with:

***x*** • ***dy***/dt + ***y*** • ***dx***/dt = 0

EXAMPLE 2
Find dy/dt:

12x² = y³ - 24

In contrast to Example 1, you begin solving the problem with
x • ***dx***/dt:

24***x*** • ***dx***/dt = 3***y***² • ***dy***/dt

COMPLETE WORKED PROBLEMS (FOR REFERENCE):

EXAMPLE 1:

Given:

xy=4

dy/dt=1

y=.5

Find dx/dt

Solution to Example 1:

x = 4/y = 4/.5 = 8

x•y=4

d/dt  [ X(t) + Y(t) ] = d/dt 8

x' • y + y' • x = 0

dx/dt • y + dy/dt • x = 0

dx/dt • .5 + 1 • 8 = 0

.5 • dx/dt = -8

dx/dt = -8/.5 = -16

EXAMPLE 2:

Given:

12x² = y³ - 24

dx/dt= -6

x= -.5

Find dy/dt

Solution to Example 2:

12•(-.5)² = y³ - 24

27=y³

y=3

12x² = y³ - 24

24 • [X(t)] • dx/dt = 3 • [Y(t)]² • dy/dt

{24 • [X(t)] • dx/dt} / 3 • [Y(t)]² = dy/dt

(24 • x • dx/dt) / (3 • y²) = dy/dt

(24 • -.5 • -6) / 27 = dy/dt

dy/dt = 72/27 = 8/3

Comment: Please give a specific example of what you mean here. Variables are only placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $x$ and $y$ as functions of $t$. So in that example you would just do the product rule
$$\frac{d}{dt} (xy) = x \frac{dy}{dt} + y \frac{dx}{dt} $$
or
$$\frac{d}{dt} [x(t)y(t)] =  x(t)y'(t) + x'(t)y(t)$$
Then for harder problems you're essentially just doing the chain rule. Like for
$$\frac{d}{dt} [x^2+y^2] = \frac{d}{dt}[x(t)^2+y(t)^2] = 2xx'(t) + 2yy'(t) = 2x \frac{dx}{dt} + 2y \frac{dy}{dt}  $$
So I suppose the general rule would be to treat your variables as functions of $t$ and do normal calculus on functions.

Comment: Thank you
Instead of::
x • dy/dt + y • dx/dt = 0
Could ou also have written?:
x • dx/dt + y • dy/dt = 0

Comment: No. That's not how the product rule works. $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ are two different objects.

Comment: You can't reorder them like that in general.
$$x(t)y'(t) + x'(t)y(t) $$
and 
$$x(t)x'(t) + y(t) y'(t) $$
are completely different functions.

Answer (score -1):

Why? Because you're using two different rules about differentiation to handle different quantities.

In the first case you are finding $\frac{d}{dt}$ of $xy$, and $x\frac{dy}{dt}$ is the first part of the **product rule** (the second part is "$+ \frac{dx}{dt}y$").

In the second case you are finding $\frac{d}{dt}$ of $12x^2$, and, if we temporarily write $w(x) = 12x^2$, then the **chain rule** says $\frac{dw}{dt} = \frac{dw}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = 12\cdot2\cdot x^1 \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$, using what you know about differentiating the function $x^2$. And in this second case you are using the **chain rule** once again on the right hand side, to deal with $\frac{d}{dt}$ of the $y^3$.

As for your "What part...." question: you're gonna have trouble if you use that version of the chain rule, with those variables, in this situation. Let's use completely new variables to try to make things clear. You use the chain rule when $a$ depends on $b$, and $b$ depends $c$. This means that $a$ depends on $c$ (when you change $c$, $b$ changes, which then changes $a$.) When you want to find exactly how $a$ changes with $c$ (i.e. calculate $\frac{da}{dc}$), the chain rules tells you that

$$ \frac{da}{dc} = \frac{da}{db} \cdot \frac{db}{dc}$$

So when you write

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$$

this implies that $y$ depends on $x$, and $x$ depends on $t$. But in your situation $x$ and $y$ both depend on $t$, separately. (Of course, there is some relationship between $x$ and $y$ in both of your problems - that's the point of related rates - but we're thinking of them as separate functions here, and are curious how each changes as $t$ changes, i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still processing, but I can already tell it's the right answer. The scenario I came up with to concretize the xy=4 problem: Water is added via a spout and removed via a separate channel.
X(t₁)=8  After you had been  measuring for 1 sec, the spout had added 8 ml
Y(t₁) = .5  After measuring for 1 sec, the channel had removed .5 ml
Y'(t₁) = 1 At exactly 1 sec after you began measuring, the channel was removing water at a rate of 1 ml/sec
X'(t₁) = -16 At exactly 1 sec after you began measuring, the spout was adding water at -16 ml/sec (Maybe it fell off, allowing water to escape.)

Comment: Cool. If you come to a final decision that it answers your question, and answers it best, you can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark  along the left side of it. That kind of closes up your question, and lets other people who find your question know which you thought was the best/final answer. (Plus I get points!)